# How to explain where I come from without implying additional meaning (e.g. ethnic origin, home)

Tags: word-choice, usage

How could I expound upon answering the question of, or referring to, to the place where I come from?

Specifically, the country of my birth and previous longterm residence; but *without* implying either genetic or emotional ties to that place?
Therefore, I am looking for substitutes / corrections for adjectives such as "ursprünglich", the verb "stammen", the noun "Herkunft" (which imply ethnic roots), and "Heimatland" (implies an ongoing personal regard for that place as "home"), to my understanding as a learner.
For this reason, I assert that this is not a duplicate of this:  [Usage of “von” and “aus” when denoting “Herkunft” (origin)](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/41632/usage-of-von-and-aus-when-denoting-herkunft-origin)  or this: [How to say "I come from Beijing, China" in German?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6917/how-to-say-i-come-from-beijing-china-in-german)

If there are no other single-word alternatives to the above, a sentence I could add in after answering the question, to convey my point of view in the spirit of the German language, would be greatly useful.

Comment: OK, then to clarify, I would like a way to convey this without implying a psychological problem or trauma.

Comment: As mentioned _Ich wurde in xxx geboren._ or _Mein Geburtsland ist xxx._ could be considered completely neutral and unemotional regarding that. Just state the fact.

Comment: People will always infer things about you no matter which words you use. Some people choose to avoid answering the question (*ich bin Weltbürger*, *ich sehe mich als Europäer*, *sind wir nicht alle Menschen?*, *ich bin überall und nirgendwo zuhause*), but many will be unable to take the hint. Others do answer, but follow up with a disclaimer: *Ich bin zwar Schwabe, aber ich spreche kein Schwäbisch.*

Comment: Antworte mit Geokoordinaten.

Comment: @userunknown Wetten, ich werde das wohl machen! XD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would simply say (and I actually do):

> Ich bin aufgewachsen in Ouagadougou.
>
> Ich bin in Schnürpflingen aufgewachsen.

This is, for my understanding, a neutral expression: it indicates the place (country, city, or whatever), but it does not imply emotional, ethnic or whatever attachment, but also not explicit detachment.

Or if it is not about your childhood and youth but rather about a place where you lived for a longer time (e.g. chiefly for working there), you might say:

> Ich habe acht Jahre in Bulgarien gelebt.
>
> Ich war ein paar Jahre in Kanada.
>
> Ich habe fünf Jahre in Leipzig verbracht.
>
> Ich habe dreißig Jahre in Großbritannien gearbeitet.

(or whereever).

Comment: Erstaunliche einfache Antwort auf eine Frage die komplizierter ist, als sie auf den ersten Blick scheint.

Comment: I still feel that this is the most appropriate way for me to go. Also, very similar, but perhaps more technical-sounding is "Ich bin gebürtiger Schnürpflinger/in." It simply informs of your birth nationality.

Answer (score 0):

> Ich wurde in Beijing geboren.

ähnlich:

> Ich stamme aus Beijing.

"Geboren" lässt, genaugenommen, offen, ob Dich Deine Mutter auf einer Reise durch China dort geboren hat, aber ohne weitere Ausführungen wird man wohl annehmen, dass Du dann auch dort einige Zeit gelebt hast.

Die Kinder einer Freundin von mir kommen aus Berlin, hier geboren und aufgewachsen, so dass sie zu ihrer Herkunft wohl nichts anderes sagen können, als Berlin (Deutschland, Westeuropa, ...) aber was sagt das über ihre Ethnie? Dass ihre Eltern aus Nigeria stammen kann man grob erraten - ich schätze das würde manchen veranlassen, eine deutsche Ethnie zu bestreiten.

Was sich andere denken, das hat man ohnehin nicht unter Kontrolle, etwa was die Verbundenheit mit der alten Heimat betrifft. Wenn jemand zu viel hineinliest, in eine knappe Äußerung - na und? Wenn es so wichtig ist, halte einen kleinen Vortrag über die genauen Zeiten, Dein aktuelles Verhältnis zu Stadt, Land, politischem Regime und ehemaligen Mitbürgern.

Answer (score 0):

Good answers so far. Let me suggest an additional option:

> Ich komme aus Afrika/England/Kuala Lumpur/….

It's the most common answer to "Wo kommst du her?", or in English: "Where do you come from?".

Also, it is not as strong as "Ich *bin* aus…" (I am from…), because "bin" has a tendency of you considering that place part of your identity.

Comment: Wenn jemand sagt, er komme aus Kanada, dann nehme ich an, dass er Kanadier ist.

Comment: @infinitezero Was meinst du damit? Meinst du "genetic or emotional ties", die laur34 ansprach? Vielleicht den staatsrechtlichen Status? Wenn ich einen neuen Ort besuche und gefragt werde, wo ich herkomme, nenne ich idR meinen Wohnsitz (d. h. das Land oder die Stadt). Wenn jemand weiter nachhakt, "Wo kommst du ursprünglich her?", meinen Geburtsort. Da geht es also nur um Biographie und weder um Genetik, Emotionen oder Staatsangehörigkeit.

Comment: Das ist ja schön, dass du deinen Wohnsitz nennst, auch wenn das eigentlich die Frage `wo wohnst du?` beantwortet. Dass Du in deinem Kommentar von Land oder Stadt sprichst und in deinem Post sogar einen Kontinent ausführst, widerspricht sich etwas. Und selbst wenn Du es so siehst, meiner Auffassung entspricht es eben nicht.

Comment: Ich sehe ja, dass wir "Ich komme aus…" unterschiedlich verstehen. Ich weiß nur nicht ganz, wie du es verstehst. Auch habe ich versucht, mein Verständnis genauer zu erklären (=wo wohnst du bzw. wo hast du bis kürzlich gewohnt). Kontinent, Land, Stadt gehört für mich alles zur Kategorie Geographie; deswegen finde ich es nicht widersprüchlich. Man kann "Ich komme aus…" auch anders verstehen, z. B. iSv "Welche Staatsangehörigkeit hast du?" oder "Welche Ethnie hast du?" Meinst du das mit "Kanadier"? Habe ich dich richtig verstanden?